# Waltec bathtub faucet still leaks after new cartridges and seats

Tags: leak

Im at a loss here. Has leaked off and on for years. Changed cartridges once seemed to solve it. This last time it started leaking it leaked more. New cartridges again. Found out about the seats. Took old ones out looked crusty.Put new ones in with new cartridges plastic oring.tried pipe tape on seat and cartridge. Same thing. Seems like cold side. What else could cause it? Just redid tub and tile wall should have changed the whole thing grr.

Comment: I forgot to mention it has thr plunger valve in the center between thr 2 faucet  for the shower. I changed the plunger there. I assume a seat behind it. Didnt change that.

Comment: Waltec and Delta are owned by the same company.  I make this point because I have had this type of issue with Delta products over decades. Finally to the point where I will not use or install any Delta plumbing product.  I don't want to debate this. I am just speaking from real world experiences.   I would rid myself of this issue and change the faucet using another brand.

Comment: You shouldn't use pipe tape on seats and cartridges. That might be the problem. The tape can prevent the seats and cartridges from sealing properly.

Comment: I first tried without the tape. Then applied tape. No difference.

Comment: Ended up taking it apart again. Scrubbed out threads where the seat screws in.dried it well and put some liquid pipe thread sealer on it with a new oring on cartridge and some liquid thread sealer on it too. Finally got the leak fixed. My tool set for the seats wouldnt go all the way in either. Used a #8 allen key to tighten it.